# SMPP Session getting closed/expired

Tags: java, smpp

I am trying to send a message, but after sending message SMPP transmitter session gets closed due to which I am not able to receive the delivery and causing problem.

```
    TCPIPConnection connection = new TCPIPConnection(smscHost, smscPort);
    connection.setReceiveTimeout(GlobalVar.BIND_TIMEOUT);

    session = new Session(connection);
    this.SystemType = systemType;
    this.NPI = NPI;
    this.TON = TON;
    pduListener = new SMPPTestPDUEventListener(session);

    BindRequest request = new BindTransmitter();
    request.setSystemId(smscUsername);
    request.setPassword(smscPassword);
    request.setSystemType(systemType);
    request.setInterfaceVersion((byte) 0x34); // SMPP protocol version

    BindResponse response = session.bind(request, pduListener);
```